# Adding an array of objects with form builder and angular material chips

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-formbuilder

i'm trying to create an array of tag objects using angular material chips.

I'm finding it very difficult figuring out how to push these tag objects into an array in my form builder.

It should be simple as i have an Array called 'selected' that holds the tag objects and I just want to add this to my form builder.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="flex col" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <mat-form-field class="chip-container">
            <mat-chip-list #chipList>
              <mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of selected" [removable]="removable" (removed)="onRemove(tag)">
                {{tag.Text}}
                <i matChipRemove *ngIf="removable" class="fal fa-times-circle"></i>
              </mat-chip>
              <input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" disabled>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </mat-form-field>

<div class="available-chips-container">
        <mat-chip-list *ngIf="!hideAvailable">
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of tags" [selectable]="selectable" (click)="onSelect(tag)">
            {{tag.Text}}
          </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
        <p class="danger-text" *ngIf="hideAvailable">Great! You have selected the maximum number of tags.</p>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here is my component code:

```
  hideAvailable: boolean;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  placeholder = 'Select a tag below...';
  selected: ITag[] = [];
  tags: ITag[];

  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      Password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ConfirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      DateOfBirth: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Tags: this.selected
  });

onSelect(tag: ITag) {
  this.selected.push(tag);
}

onRemove(tag: ITag): void {
  this.tags.push(tag);
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.registerForm.value)
}
```

The issue at the moment is that event though im pushing tags into the selected array and they are being pushed in fine, the registerForm.value Tags array is always empty when the form is submitted using onSubmit().

Please let me know if you need any further code.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `registerForm` in the **html**? Have you posted a portion of the code or something? Try adding `{{JSON.stringify(registerForm.value)}}` to bottom of html to debug

Comment: Where in the component does this.registerForm reside? Need to know method it's in

Comment: Have updated the code. registerForm wraps the form elements. The form is pretty large so I've left out the other formControls for now to keep the above shorter

Answer (score 2):

`selected` seems to be just a JS array, not a `FormArray`. You need to tell angular that selected is a `FormArray` and depending on the case, either push form controls, or form groups into that array. I guess you want formgroups in this case. So declare a form array when you build your form:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    // ...
    Tags: this.fb.array([])
  });
}
```

Then on add, we push formgroups to the formarray, we define a getter for the formarray for easier use in functions and template.

```ts
get tagsArr() {
  return this.registerForm.get('Tags') as FormArray;
}
```

Then the add and remove:

```ts
onSelect(tag: any) {
  /** if you only want formcontrol with a single value use: 
      this.tagsArr.push(tag.Text), else do below
  **/
  this.tagsArr.push(
    this.fb.group({
      Text: tag.Text
      // other props
    })
  )
}

onRemove(index): void {
  this.tagsArr.removeAt(index);
}
```

Then in template we iterate the formarray and display form control values:

```html
<mat-chip-list #chipList formArrayName="Tags">
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of tagsArr.controls; let i = index" 
                    [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(i)" >
    {{tag.get('Text').value}}
    <i matChipRemove *ngIf="removable" class="fal fa-times-circle"></i>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zryp9u?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)** example

Answer (score 1):

You are using fb as a FormBuilder right.

The FormControl is the syntax you use when you are doing it the 'hard way'.

fb avoids that!

Examples below from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-defining-a-formarray-control):

**Hard way:**

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl(''),
  address: new FormGroup({
    street: new FormControl(''),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    state: new FormControl(''),
    zip: new FormControl('')
  })
});
```

vs

**Easy way:**

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: [''],
  lastName: [''],
  address: this.fb.group({
    street: [''],
    city: [''],
    state: [''],
    zip: ['']
  }),
});
```

This is a simple example I have in one of my Ionic apps called during initialisation phase.

i.e. you remove all the `new FormControl(` ... `)`

```
 this.gvarForm = this.fb.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          value: ['', Validators.required],
      });
```

Let me know if you still have issues after the refactor.
with this bit added to the html

```
{{JSON.stringify(registerForm.value)}}
```

(Only I am still not sure about the headline.

> Adding an array of objects with form builder and angular material
>   chips

I am assuming you have a list of tags that you add to another component dynamically).

Some screenshots - even if you use something crude like Paint, Preview, or a scanned handwritten UI scrawl would help solidify my understanding.

In the meantime, [this](https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da) might help too.